# How do I "identify with services" on IRC?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, irc, irssi

I am using irrsi as my irc cilent on ubuntu
I have entered "/join #android-dev" in my command window.
But I am getting this error message:

```
22:05 -!- #android-dev Cannot join channel (+r) - you need to be identified 
          with services
```

Can you please tell me how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 125):

You need to register an account with the services robots. To do this, send the NickServ a "register" command. The syntax for this is generally like this:

`/msg nickserv register [password] [email]`

where [password] is a password you would like to use to identify yourself, and [email] is... well, an email address you can be contacted at (used only for password recovery).

Then, when you connect, you'll see a message like this:

`This nickname is registered. Please choose a different nickname, or identify...`

You'll then need to send the "identify" command:

`/msg nickserv identify [password]`

where [password] is the password you set before. You'll then be logged in to the services.

Requiring that you be authenticated to the services is just an anti-spam/anti-abuse measure by the channel, it requires that you go to a little extra effort to join that griefers probably won't.

Comment: where should i type these commands?

Comment: In Status window.

Comment: Did not work on `https://webchat.freenode.net` (on chrome): I just enter the chat and type `/msg NickServ REGISTER pAsSwOrd youremail@example.com` output: 
`[22:08] -NickServ- The nick Guest63156 is reserved and cannot be registered.`

Comment: I solved it: at the page `https://webchat.freenode.net/`at the beginning don't forget to check the box Auth to services. Fill your username + password. It will creates your `nick`. Then do `/msg NickServ REGISTER password (using the password you just gave) youremail@example.com` and follow the instruction.

Comment: Ok I've already done that once and connected succesfully, but it's giving this error each time I connect, any idea why?

Answer (score 16):

OK, for anyone like me who did not grasp this simple process at first :). Here is a much expanded answer, using a different IRC service, webchat, which runs on a browser.

To use IRC for the first time:

1.Go to a url that hosts IRC such as; 
http://webchat.freenode.net/

2.Login anonymously at first because you have not yet registered.

2a.Enter your desired username handle, a chat room you wish to enter, and answer the captcha question.
2a1.Do not use 'Auth to services' checkbox, which only works after you register.
2a2.The Audio captcha checkbox is provided if you prefer a sound.
2b.Here is a screenshot of the GUI, via a nice Youtube, 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ypbZ_5mmF-o#t=157
[image: Pic of Webchat Login Screen]

3.The system will open into the IRC console.

4.The last message may notify you that your desired chatroom cannot be accessed because you have not yet registered your email address.

```
==#pyladies Cannot join channel (+r) - you need to be identified with services
```

5.To explore and see what commands are available, any of these commands may help you.  (There is a white box at the bottom of the screen for entry of commands.)

```
/msg nickserv help
/msg nickserv help register
/msg nickserv help commands
```

6.To fix the lack of registration, first tell the system what password and email address you prefer.

6a.Do NOT use a secure password; you are on HTTP!
6b.Example;

```
/msg NickServ REGISTER yourDesiredPassword yourEmailAddress
```

7.Check your email and type the message it provides for you, such as;

```
/msg NickServ VERIFY REGISTER  yourHandleUserid yourSpecialCode
```

8.You cannot successfully run

```
/join #yourDesiredChannel
```

yet, because you are still officially anonymous.

9.Quit the session, eg close the tab, and re-login, this time using authentication.

10.Hopefully you are redirected directly into the chatroom and the wide world of IRC!

Comment: > /msg NickServ REGISTER yourDesiredPassword yourEmailAddress  
  
help for me, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You must first register your nickname with the nickname-registering services. Try

`/msg nickserv help`

and register your nickname.

Answer (score 1):

At each login you can do

```
/msg NickServ identify your_password_here
```

Probably you also can make it automatic somehow