# noob on freenode wondering what "auth to services" checkbox does. Already registered Nick

Tags: irc, freenode

New to freenode wondering what "auth to services" checkbox does? I have Already registered Nick.

Comment: What "auth to services" checkbox?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101277/what-does-auth-to-services-option-mean-in-irc and https://superuser.com/questions/106965/how-do-i-identify-with-services-on-irc/727142#727142

Comment: thank you for your help :) I found it too:  The "Auth to Services" option lets you log in when you have registered with Freenode's NickServ, which reserves your nickname and provides other privileges.

Answer (score 0):

When you auth, you reset the timer on nick aging, which would otherwise allow your name to be reused by others if you stop using the service for a while (i think its 6 months, might be more). It's also useful for situations where you're logged in from two places, or someone else has your name in use.

i.e: Say you log in from home and find either someone using your name (but obviously not authed to services as that name), or your other computer which is turned on at work is still using the name. You can auth to services as your nick, and then 'ghost' that other user, which forces them to change names and frees up your usual name. It's very handy for stopping people using your name who aren't actually you.

Comment: Thank you Sirex I appreciate understanding more about it thanks to you :)